# Android - how to get access token of one drive

Tags: android, onedrive

```
Account account = new Account("xxxx@xxx.com", "com.microsoft.skydrive");

AccountManagerFuture accFut = AccountManager.get(this).
getAuthToken(account, "sh", null, this, null, null);

Bundle authTokenBundle = (Bundle) accFut.getResult();

String authToken = authTokenBundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
```

**This code is not working.**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate your Android app with OneDrive, you can start with [OneDrive Android SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android). Simply you can get an access token in your app by

```
oneDriveClient.getAuthenticator().getAccountInfo().getAccessToken();
```